# How to use onkeypress to capture variable data?

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

I am very new to learning javascript and jquery. I have been given a lot of assignments that require a user to tap on any key on the keyboard to play a game or submit a guess. It would not be to difficult for me to set up if the user could use a prompt (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) or a confirm (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) to capture data for the variable with an input field. I have been trying to figure out a way to do this with the onkeypress . Does anyone know how to capture a variable data using this command?

here is a little bit of code that I tried to use:

```
     document.onkeydown = function user (event) {
    var key_press = String.fromCharCode (event.keyCode);
    document.getElementById("kp").innerHTML = key_press;
    return event;
    }
    console.log(event);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using `addEventListener` with `keypress` as the first argument. Something like this:

```js
const outputEl = document.querySelector('#output');
document.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  outputEl.innerHTML = `<p>User pressed: ${e.code}</p>`;
});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```